# Is there a web browser component for use in FireMonkey application?

Tags: delphi, webbrowser-control, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

For Delphi VCL there is [`TWebBrowser`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/SHDocVw.TWebBrowser) and some 3rd party components like [`TEmbeddedWebBrowser`](http://www.bsalsa.com/downloads.html) available for browsing a web.

Is there a similar web browser component but for **Firemonkey** framework in **Delphi XE2** (ideally with Windows and Mac support) ?

Comment: Hi Dennies, have you tried to use the ChromiumEmbedded on Mac ? Have you resolved this somehow ? Any feedback will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: any possibility to just write a native app? By the time you figure out how to make Delphi/FireMonkey work, you will be well along with getting your native app written... Just a thought. :-| Plus, I don't think I've ever seen a cross-platform app that delivered an acceptable user experience.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the [`ChromiumEmbedded`](http://delphichromiumembedded.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/) package for Delphi. There's a `TChromiumFMX` component which is suited for `FireMonkey` applications. I've tested the [`demo project`](http://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/source/browse/trunk/demos/firemonkey/?r=119) from the repository and it works fine for 32-bit Windows.

However I can't tell you if nor how to build and use it in Mac OS. The only thing I can tell you is that the [`ChromiumEmbedded`](http://delphichromiumembedded.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/) for Delphi is distributed only with Windows binaries, the binaries for Mac OS you can download from [`here`](http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/downloads/detail?name=cef_binary_r306_macosx.zip&can=2&q=).

Comment: I downloaded CEF3, but `TChromiumFMX` wasn't included with the package it seems. Any ideas?

Comment: @petersmileyface, it seems that [`there won't be any`](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/delphichromiumembedded/I39FHay1npY/ozDpF5OAtz0J) as Jørgen Opsand [`cited here`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327111/is-there-a-web-browser-component-for-use-in-firemonkey-application/9327827?noredirect=1#comment18702418_13624746) from the linked thread.

Comment: I have tried but doesn't work on Win7/DXE2. I get run-time error

Comment: @Mohammad, make sure you [`have core libraries visible to your executable`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9587241/960757). That's the most common mistake. But that's all I can tell you, because I don't know what error you got, when, nor which version of DCEF you used.

Comment: Thank you @TLama. I had the core library but seems I was using an old version. however it supped to work on XE2. Anyway, I got a newer version from https://code.google.com/p/dcef3/ and worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know (!), the situation is as follows:

- CromiumEmbedded supports OSX (& Windows of course)
- There is a Delphi ChromiumEmbedded
- Delphi supports OSX through the FireMonkey framework
- There is even a FireMonkey version of the Delphi ChromiumEmbedded
- The Delphi/FireMonkey ChromiumEmbedded does not support OSX

If somebody knows better, that would be fantastic.

Comment: Don't forget on new [`Chromium CEF3`](http://code.google.com/p/dcef3/) wrapper for Delphi.

Comment: Henri Gourvest, has stated on the delphichromiumembedded forum that "Current version of CEF3 do not have offscreen rendering, so I can't create Firemonkey compatible Component".  CEF1 has the FireMonkey Component, but not (yet?) OSX support.