# Embed Web Browser in MacOS Application using Delphi XE2

Tags: macos, delphi, webkit, delphi-xe2

How can I embed a WebView (Embedded Web browser) inside a Delphi MacOS application?

It does not appear the webkit headers are included in [XE2.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003822)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use FireMonkey to browse Web URL with Delphi XE2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327111/how-to-use-firemonkey-to-browse-web-url-with-delphi-xe2)

Comment: Hello. As far as I know the web browser in Delphi is a kind of wrapper for Internet Explorer, so it can not be used under MacOS. You should follow Warren P's link.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the TWebBrowser control?  This control works in the iOS environment and you can simply set it's URL or use the Navigate function.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Chromium Embedded Framework](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/)? It might be kinda heavyweight if you just want a view with some HTML, but they have bindings for Delphi. You get access to an up to date chrome webkit/blink browser with V8.