# Using TChromium, Delphi Chromium Embedded

Tags: delphi, chromium, chromium-embedded, tchromium

This is a continuation of my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518594/javascript-in-delphi-twebbrowser-closing-threads). In that question I showed a problem involving TWebBrowser generating threads that persisted after the Browsers destruction. While noone could provide a solution to the problem, it was suggested that the problem could be a non-fixable one (a flaw with the TWebBrowser component itself).

Because of this I have attempted to download and use the [Delphi Chromium Embedded Framework](http://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/). I downloaded the components and added them to Delphi, added one to a new form and attempted to run the program, at which point it throws up a CPU break point at

`5264DF81 6A01             push $01`

Module Load: icudt46.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $562C0000. Process DCEFTestRun.exe (3080)

There is no error message, but when the program is continued manually it closes. I have had no experience with DCEF before, nor any experience using 3rd party components and the DCEF site is sorely lacking in documentation.

I suppose the easiest thing i'm asking for is a simple walkthrough (very basic) of what to download/install and where to get the Chromium Components to work.

Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are missing the [`Chromium Embedded Framework`](http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/) (CEF) core libraries. It is enough to copy the content of the [`..\dcef\bin\Win32`](http://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/source/browse/#svn/trunk/bin/Win32) folder (from your downloaded package) into your project's output directory (or into some of the [`known folders`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) location reachable from your project's executable).

Comment: Please elaborate. What does this do? How does this fix whatever was wrong in the question?

Comment: @Rob, I don't know how to elaborate this more than if you got this kind of the error you are probably missing the core CEF libraries (that was the first what came to my mind; it's from my personal experience :-)

Comment: I just wondered how you got from "breakpoint on an isolated `push` instruction" to "missing libraries." Doesn't the OS loader usually complain when there are missing libraries and refuse to load the binary at all? Or wouldn't there be a failed `LoadLibrary` call? (Or maybe there was, and since you've seen these symptoms before, you just didn't explain all the investigation you did before.)