# Install Chrome and Extensions by Delphi

Tags: delphi, google-chrome

I'm integrating Chrome with an application that is in development and am facing some setbacks.

At first I have to **installing** Chrome and an extension on it, is there any way to do this via codes?
Install Chrome itself is the problem easy to install this extension.

Can I appeal also to make a backup of the settings and then restore them, but do not know how to perform this process.

Thank you.

Comment: you can always use CEF which works independently from Chrome

Comment: Excuse the ignorance but what is "CEF"?

Comment: Chromium embedded framework, a standalone version of chrome to embed in applications, you just need to deploy one dll with your application. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9587241/800214

Comment: I already have knowledge of this component, the problem is that it does not support the extensions, has neither how to install it ...

thank you

Comment: you can add plugins to CEF by setting the cefextrapluginpaths property of the global configuration

Comment: Sorry, but I am a layman in this matter, which is the property that should I change?