# Delphi: Getting error `Exception EOSError` when compile TChromium(dcef3)

Tags: delphi, chromium

I installed the latest Chromium Embbed version on XE6, did a test using demo `guiclient` and worked very well. But when I create a new app and put TChromium component receive this error:

[image]

I did the tips on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587021/using-tchromium-delphi-chromium-embedded?rq=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually that means that a 32 bit process is attempting to load a 64 bit module, or vice versa. You need to do a bit of debugging, for instance using Dependency Viewer, to work out which module has the wrong bitness.

One obvious possibility is that your host process is 64 bit and the CEF libraries are 32 bit. To fix that you would need to switch your process to be 32 bit, or find 64 bit CEF libraries. I'm not even sure if the latter exist.

Comment: Was running on 32bit, I debug as you mencinou and realized that he was carrying the 64bit libraries, I had to delete the files on it in the ... \ SysWOW64 and removes library path in Delphi, thanks.

Comment: @Artur_Indio How did 64bit binaries wind up in `SysWOW64` and how was it even working to begin with?

Comment: In dcef3 files there are two folders `bin` with win 32 and 64 files , I had put the files in the System32 and SysWOW64 folders, and put the path's regarding the library path of Delphi.

Comment: You should not modify system directories. Put the CEF DLLs in the same directory as your executable file.